# The complete Legendre transformation of $U$ is zero

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

The fact that $U(S, V, N_1, N_2 , ... )$ is a homogeneous first-order function of its arguments causes the complete Legendre transformation of $U$ to vanish. But as it vanishes, how can we recover information from this zero function? I mean, we can't take it's partial derivative, because that's would be zero. Does the function being zero brings some other consequences, or is it just the same as other partial Legendre transformation of $U$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vanishing of the Legendre transformation with respect to all the (extensive) variables of $U$, more than defining a new function, is a signal that the Legendre transformation process, in that case, fails. Formally, it works, but it is missing the main aim of the transformation.

The reason is the constraint the homogeneity of degree one puts on the functional dependence of $U$ on its variables. For simplicity, I'll discuss the case of a one-component system. Extension to many-component systems is trivial.

Homogeneity of degree one requires that
$$
U(\lambda S, \lambda V, \lambda N )= \lambda  U(S,V,N)   \tag{1}                                            
$$
for every $ S,V,N$, and for every $\lambda>0$. In particular, once we have fixed the value of $N$, we can choose $\lambda=\frac{1}{N}$.
Equation ($1$) gives
$$
U(S,V,N) = N U\left(\frac{S}{N},\frac{V}{N},1      \right)=  N u(s,v)\tag{2},
$$
where the lowercase letters indicate the corresponding uppercase variables "per particle."

The structure of equation $(2)$ is relatively simple: there is a change of variables ( $S,V,N \rightarrow s=S/N,v=V/N,N $) such that the dependence on $N$ is linear.

A Legendre transformation aims to substitute the dependence on one variable of the function $U$ with the dependence on the first derivative with respect to the same variable. To have a Legendre transformation defined on an interval in the new variable, the original function cannot be linear: a linear function has the same value of the first derivative everywhere.

Therefore, the complete Legendre transformation gives the (useless) zero function because one of the functional dependencies can be cast as a linear function with a change of variables.

Notice, however, that in real finite-size thermodynamic systems, the homogeneity of degree one is only an approximation, equivalent to neglecting surface effects. In this case, the complete Legendre transformation can be used to make the surface contributions to thermodynamics evident.